# After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04, I cannot run terminal and many apps don't load

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, upgrade, 18.04

Having run 16.04 happily, I thought I would try an upgrade to 18.04. This went fairly smoothly.
However, now I notice many issues, which are stopping the system working well. One main one is that when I try to run terminal, this never loads.
I wonder if it is because I was running the gnome interface in 16.04, as I couldn't get on with the unity interface.
Should I try to remove the 16.04 gnome interface, or will that cause more issues?
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: what made you not do a fresh boot install? This problem occurred to me when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. I highly recommend you to do a fresh install or you will purge every single package from previous version manually.

Comment: Try this... at the login screen, select your username, then click the cog wheel icon, then select `Ubuntu`, then enter your password. If that works, let me know, and I'll write this as an answer that you can formally accept. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Many thanks for all the help.
I tried logging in and using the cog to log in under Ubuntu, but that meant I couldn't use anything, and all I could do was to log out and back in - and then I was able to run terminal. I did then try to run the commands outlined by Shaze (many thanks) and I saw that my files were as they should be. It is good to know that I did have Bionic Beaver installed, and that I will be notified of LTS versions.
My thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this command after the following steps? -

This should be your last step - `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

**Step 1:** Update Ubuntu 16.04 Server
Before upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, you should first update the current 16.04. It’s recommended to update/upgrade all installed packages before upgrading. To update Ubuntu, connect to the server and run the commands below:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

**Step 2:** Install Ubuntu Update Manager
After updating Ubuntu 16.04 server, run the commands below to install update-manager-core if it is not already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Then open the update-manager configuration file and make sure the Prompt line is set to lts

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Confirm that the Prompt is equal lts

Default behavior for the release upgrader.

```
[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
If not, change it to lts and save the file.
```

**Step 3:** Perform Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Upgrade
Now that your system is ready, run the commands below to begin Ubuntu upgrade to the latest development release..

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I hd a similar problem with 18.04.2 and ended up moving up to 18.10 and that pushed me past this.  There seems to be an issue with some kernel sub-versions of 18.04